# Output three colums from my mysql database php

Tags: php, arrays, database, mysqli, foreach

I'm a beginner in php and i'd like to output 3 fields from my database to my website which included a bloc image,text and name. using a foreach i can only get 2 out of the three.

```
<table border="2px">
    <tr>
        <th> Brand</th>
        <th> Images</th>
        <th> Details</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    $tex   = [];
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM upload");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $images[] = $row['image'];
        $br[]     = $row['name'];
        $det[]    = $row['text'];
    }
    foreach (array_combine($det, $images) as $text => $image) {
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $name;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'"/>';
        echo "<td>";
        echo $text;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</td></tr>";
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

that is a snippet of my code where images and text is outputted on the screen and receive and undefined variable in error in line 39 which would be `echo $name;`. what should i put in the foreach statement to get it to output all three?

```
$images[] = $row['image'];
$br[]     = $row['name'];
$det[]    = $row['text'];
```

can someone explain these to me as i have an idea what it is doing but i want to be 100.

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $images[] = $row['image'];
    $br[]     = $row['name'];
    $det[]    = $row['text'];
}
foreach ($images as $idx => $image) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $br[$idx];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'"/>';
    echo "<td>";
    echo $det[$idx];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

You are combining only `text` and `image`. That way you would not know which `name` is the corresponding one. My loop solves this by using the index (`$idx`) for that. All arrays have the same size, so this works.

Answer (score 1):

There's no point using a separate `foreach` loop like that. You should simply change your `while` loop like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo"<tr><td>"; 
    echo $row['name']; 
    echo "</td>"; 
    echo "<td>"; 
    echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($row['image']) .'"/>';
    echo"<td>";
    echo $row['text'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo"</td></tr>";
}
```